# How should I use Git to manage files owned by root?

Tags: git, ubuntu, sudo, configuration-files

Unfortunately when trying to version root-permission config files, git operations changing or reading them need to be run using sudo.

Meanwhile, other git operations (like pushing changes to the master repo on Github) need to be run without sudo, since otherwise they run without proper access to the SSH keys from my user account.

Additionally, index files in .git in the repo end up being owned by root when running as sudo, which then breaks later operations which need to run without sudo, but which try to update pre-existing files in .git.

What is a suitable configuration which would eliminate these conflicts between the contradictory need to both RUN and NOT RUN with sudo? How can I achieve this configuration?

For example...

a) should I run git WITH sudo consistently, while configuring it specially to access my user account SSH keys independently of the running user somehow.
b) should I run git WITHOUT sudo consistently, while configuring it to use sudo when it needs to write or access root-owned files somehow.

BACKGROUND

I would like to version files used to configure my Ubuntu desktop. This means when I am trying to repeat the same configuration on a future desktop (or the same desktop after a rebuild), it is easy to see which lines were changed, and even search for config file changes by 'feature description'.

The approach involves configuring a repository with a working tree outside itself (supported by git), then adding and committing the unmodified (stock) version of a config file before changing it and then committing the change with a decent commit message.

Answer (score 0):

I'm always disabling git tracking file permissions by `git config core.fileMode false`.

I think it ok to manage file permissions by working environment (develop / production) and not by git himself.

Comment: This is interesting, but not directly connected to the question. In the case I am describing, the files are edited and maintain permissions exactly as normal for config files. That is to say I expect each config file to be owned by root, and have the standard permissions determined by the package. However, I am aiming to a) version them against a local git repo, and b) synchronise that git repo to github. a) relies on running as sudo, b) relies on NOT running as sudo . Hence the puzzle. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: I'm confused by your answer. What does setting `core.fileMode false` accomplish? I don't know what you mean by "manage file permissions by working environment". Can you explain?

Comment: After reading up on `fileMode` I found that it does not solve the problem. The problem is that commands such as `git commit` cannot be run without sudo, and if you try to do `sudo git push`, your changes may be rejected because of you are operating as `root`, and therefore your credentials are wrong.